# From Categories MySQL table to MongoDB design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I come from MySQL background and I am trying to learn MongoDB.  I have **product documents**, and each product document has a category.  Right now I am letting the user choose the category manually but what I want is to show a drop down menu with all the categories that have been defined by me.

In MySQL I would create a **categories table** and get all of those and show them to the user. How would I store those categories in MongoDB?

Comment: Is the list of categories dynamic? Do you want to add more on the fly?

Comment: It should be dynamic yes. I want to be able to add more categories in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would still have a categories collection and have an ObjectId pointer to the other collection, just so that you can have a single master list of all the categories but still also have the embedded category in the document so that you can perform searches based on that. You won't have full relationship but you can keep track of the categories avail in a single place.

IMO, The philosophy of mongo does not mean to get rid of all relations but just to have them where it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I thought about having a collection but.. Each document of that collection would be so simple: id, category_name. Would I create a collection just for that?

Comment: you can always add extra metadata like creation time, description, in any case as your application grows you can use that collection to also describe sub-categories.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could have a category collection from which the user can choose categories and simply store the categories as an array of strings in your products documents. This avoids worrying about joining the data when you want to display the product or find products based on categories.

Comment: I'm in the process of designing the same thing, and I think I'm going to do what @michaeltwofish and juan outlined. Then on the admin side of things, just populate a combo list with the category names from the categories collection and store that string directly in the master (product) document as its category.